# memcpy correct implementation approach

Tags: c, algorithm, buffer, memcpy

I`ve found the following implementation for the memcpy (interview question,where the iteration count ~ size/4):

```
void memcpy(void* dest, void* src, int size)
{
    uint8_t *pdest = (uint8_t*) dest;
    uint8_t *psrc = (uint8_t*) src;

    int loops = (size / sizeof(uint32_t));
    for(int index = 0; index < loops; ++index)
    {
        *((uint32_t*)pdest) = *((uint32_t*)psrc);
        pdest += sizeof(uint32_t);
        psrc += sizeof(uint32_t);
    }

    loops = (size % sizeof(uint32_t));
    for (int index = 0; index < loops; ++index)
    {
        *pdest = *psrc;
        ++pdest;
        ++psrc;
    }
}
```

And I am not sure I understand it .....:

1) Why to define `uint8_t *pdest,uint8_t *psrc` and after that to make casting to `uint32_t` -

```
*((uint32_t*)pdest) = *((uint32_t*)psrc);
```

I think that from the beginning `pdest` and `psrc` should be defined as uint32_t...What I am missing?
2)It looks to me that there is a problem with this implementation:
if `src = 0x100` and `dst = 0x104`
and the src (originally)looks like that :

```
-------------------------
|  6  |  8  |  7  |  1  |
-------------------------    
0x100  0x104 0x108 0x1C0
```

after the execution it will be like that

```
-------------------------
|  6  |  6  |  6  |  6  |.....
-------------------------
0x100  0x104 0x108 0x1C0
```

despite that looks the following memory layout should be a result

```
-------------------------
|  6  |  6  |  8  |  7  |....
-------------------------
0x100  0x104 0x108 0x1C0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This `memcpy()` suffers another problem: what happens if one or both buffers are not on a proper boundary? This could affect performance significantly or, on some architectures, make code not even run. Another common problem (but not here) is dealing with buffers whose length is not a multiple of the width of the native (uint32) type. The reason your example is using a uint8 type (and then casting as needed) is to allow trailing bytes to be copied without casting. It makes no difference if you cast the bulk of the transfer or just the trailing bytes. To account for buffer alignment, you would expect something early to copy initial non-aligned data until an alignment is established.

The `memcpy()` function is not guaranteed to work in a defined manner when the source and destination overlap; for that reason the problem you label as number two is not a problem. If instead of `memcpy()`, this code were used in an implementation of `memmove()`, then the problem would be real.

Answer (score 0):

regarding pointer type: the idea here is that in order to reduce both loop and copy overhead, you want to copy using the largest data "chunks" (say 32bit) possible.
So you try to copy as much as possible using 32bit words.
The remainder then needs to be copied in smaller 8bit "chunks".
For example, if you want to copy 13 bytes, you would do 3 iterations copying 32bit word + 1 iteration copying a single byte. This is preferable to doing 13 iterations of single byte copy.
You could convert to uint32_t*, but then you'll have to convert back to uint8_t* to do the remainder.

Regarding the second issue - this implementation will not work properly in case the destination address overlapps the source buffer. Assuming you want to support this kind of memcpy as well - it is a bug.
This is a popular interview question pitfall ;).

Comment: If you said this was a bug for memcpy() in an interview, you might lose a little credit. Per man pages I've reviewed today for both OS X and Linux, memcpy() does not support overlapping buffers, so the bug would be owned by the caller, not by the memcpy() function itself. The memmove() function allows overlapping buffers.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop goes through and copies memory from psrc to pdest in chunks of 4 bytes per loop, hence the cast to uint32_t*.  The second loop copies the remaining memory in chunks of 1 byte. For large chunks of memory, this effectively cuts down the number of iterations by a factor of 4.

As to the reason why the cast is to uint8_t* instead of uint32_t*. With a cast directly to uint32_t*, the first loop would work fine however you would need to increment the pointers by 1 instead of 4 each loop. You would get something like the following

```
for(int index = 0; index < loops; ++index)
{
    *(pdest) = *(psrc); //no need for cast
    pdest++;            //increment by 1 not 4
    psrc++;
}
```

However with the second loop you would need to cast to uint8_t*, and increment the pointer by 1/4.  There is no way to do this with pointer arithmetic, so it is not possible to do it this way.

Another way to think about it:
loops1: The number of 4 byte chunks in the original memory block
loops2: The number of bytes left over